# sencha touch2 Login examples

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I need a cross-domain user login request instance, please help me, thank you！！
My code

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
      url: 'http://25.30.2.3:8080/newvbo/applyaction!longin',
      params: {
            username:'13881901678',
            password:'111111',
      },
      success: function(response, opts) {    
             alert('1');      
     },
     failure: function(response, opts) {
            alert('2');     
     }
});
```

My question is, I not receive the server returns the value, I wrong?

Comment: What back end are you using ?

Comment: I think maybe your server response not jsonp, check the callback param. the response should something like this your_callback_key({'data':'hello'})

Answer (score 3):

You can Try this

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
method:'GET',
contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
dataType:'json',
url:'http://........Login',
disableCaching: false,
withCredentials: true,
useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
callbackKey: 'callback',

params: {
        EmailId:Ext.getCmp('usernametwoway').getValue(),
        Password:Ext.getCmp('loginpasswordtwoway').getValue(),
        },


success:function(response)
{
        console.log(response);
        var res = response.responseText;    


        var jsonarr = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
        console.log(jsonarr);
            var myres = jsonarr[0].Result;

            console.log(myres);
        switch(myres)
            {

            case '1':
            console.log("Registration response is successfully");

            Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem({xtype:'passengerdetailstwoway'});

            break;

            case '0':
                console.log("Failed");
                Ext.Msg.alert("Error","Login Failed",Ext.emptyFn);
                break;
```

Based on the responce you can Specify the Switch case..

Answer (score 0):

Hi @jesse you can try for cross-domain something like this,

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
       url: 'your_url_path',
       timeout: 90000,
       params: {
             withCredentials: true,
             useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
             username:'13881901678',
             password:'111111',
       },
       success: function(response, o) {
             if(response != '') {
                   alert('1')
             }
       },
       failure: function(response, o) {
             alert('2')
       }
 })
```

For cross-domain you need put `withCredentials: true` and `useDefaultXhrHeader: false`.

I hope help you.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the problem now is in the chrome debugging, there Uncaught SyntaxError is: Unexpected Token:
See the return code in Java debugging: {"jsonArray": null, "jsonMap": null, "jsonReturn": "true"}
In the end I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe, but your response's are `null` can you show me how do you doing the request? :)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you a different approach because sending login credentials as GET parameter to remote server over http is not a good idea, instead you should use POST method over HTTPS. Now you would think JSONP doesn't support POST so how can I do this, but if you are going to install your app on Phone or iPad it would do remote call from browser without using JsonP, which means you can use normal AJAX proxy to do whatever you want. Check this out:

[How to use json proxy to access remote services during development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118053/how-to-use-json-proxy-to-access-remote-services-during-development)

Which means this should work:

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.userId = username;
obj.password = password;
var data = Ext.JSON.encode(obj);

Ext.Ajax.request({
    url : 'https://login_url',
    method : "POST",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    params : data,
    useDefaultXhrHeader : false,
    withCredentials: true,
    success : function(response) {

    },
    failure : function(response) {

    }
});
```