# How to use json proxy to access remote services during development

Tags: javascript, extjs, cross-browser, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

This is my doubt after going through

[How to send headers while using jsonp proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681426/how-to-send-headers-while-using-jsonp-proxy/13984162#comment19534245_13984162)

and

[How Ajax call is working in mobile app (PhoneGap), but not in PC browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440725/how-ajax-call-is-working-in-mobile-app-phonegap-but-not-in-pc-browser)

As per this we can use json proxy instead of jsonp in mobile but not in desktop browser. This sounds good but my problem is I am using my desktop as develop environment and browser is quickest way to test and debug whatever I am doing but if I use json proxy this won't work because of cross domain issues. Please suggest ways such that I can easily develop and debug application on my desktop itself.

My workstation has Ubuntu OS and I use Chrome browser for testing.

Comment: create a proxy file on your localhost?? For example in php can be a simple one line `echo file_get_contents(url)`

Comment: Can you enable cross domain access in your dev environment? If you can try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain and http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: What server are you running on your local development environment? I had similar issues until I started using Sencha's CMD line to start a little server for my project. http://www.ladysign-apps.com/developer/environment/use-the-sencha-cmd-webserver/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for the development purpose you can disable cross domain policy in your browser as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/chrome-disable-same-origin-policy).

1. create a short cut for the chrome browser in you desktop
2. add the following flag to the short cut `--disable-web-security`

Or

You can setup your dev server to allow cross domain requests as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain) or [here]

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/chrome-disable-same-origin-policy).
Add the following header to your response `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Comment: In case it is not working for you, please kill all chrome instances and start it with this flag. BTW here is my shortcut's target `/usr/bin/chromium-browser %U --disable-web-security`