# Loading store data with rest proxy from server in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: rest, proxy, load, sencha-touch-2, store

I have searched around on the forums and read some other posts. However, I'm not sure how exactly to go about this. I have a store with a proxy that I'm trying to load with data from a server. I have tried both jsonp and rest for the type of proxy without luck. In both cases I get a 403 forbidden error. followed by an XMLHTTPRequest cannot load error.

Here's the error that I see in the Chrome console:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
Ext.define('EventsTest.store.Venues', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',


    requires: [
        'Ext.data.proxy.Rest',
    ],


    config: {
        storeId: 'venuesStore',
        model: 'EventsTest.model.Venue',
        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            url: 'http://leo.web/pages/api/',
            headers: {
                'x-api-key': 'senchaleotestkey'
            },
            limitParam: false,
            pageParam: false,
            enablePagingParams: false
            /*
            extraParams: {
                latitude: 45.250157,
                longitude: -75.800257,
                radius: 5000
            }
            */
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Security policy in browser and desktop is different so even if it fails in browser it can work in phone. But now the question is how to manage while you are developing the app, for that have a look at this similar question :

[How to use json proxy to access remote services during development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118053/how-to-use-json-proxy-to-access-remote-services-during-development/14118164#14118164)

Regarding that OPTION request which is getting 403 response, try setting `withCredentials : false` and `useDefaultHeader : false`. Details here

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Operation-cfg-withCredentials 
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Connection-cfg-useDefaultHeader

I would suggest you to read more about `CORS` if you want to use remote services, you may choose to enable `CORS` on your server.

Comment: Thanks Floyd. I found that after testing on the device, CORS was handled perfectly by PhoneGap and I didn't have any such issues. I was able to run REST as well as JSONP calls just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're running your app on a local domain "sencha.test", but you're trying to access data on "leo.web" - the error is that you're trying to load data across domains, which isn't allowed via AJAX.

You say that JSONP doesn't work... why not? Does your server return valid JSONP?

Comment: Using JSONP returns 403 Forbidden and no valid data is returned. The reason that I'm using REST is that JSONP does not support POST method for requests.

Comment: If JSONP requests are hitting a 403 error, I suspect it's an issue with your server configuration or API... but you are correct in that all JSONP requests will be GET operations. If you have to do cross-domain requests to a REST API, I might suggest using a server-side proxy to handle things.