# Sencha touch create update delete by using jersey

Tags: java, jersey, sencha-touch-2, crud

I am new for `sencha touch`. I need to create, delete, update a member record throughout `jersey` java. Here is my code

`view.js`

```
    Ext.define('bluebutton.view.BlueButton.testing', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'testing',
       requires: [

    'bluebutton.view.BlueButton.TransactionList',
    'bluebutton.view.BlueButton.MemberPopUp',
     'bluebutton.view.BlueButton.MemberDetail',
     'bluebutton.store.BlueButton.MemberList',

    ],
    config: {
     id:'register',
        items :[

              {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'name',
                    label: 'Name'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'emailfield',
                    name: 'email',
                    label: 'Email'
                },

                 {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Send',
                    handler: function(button) {
                        var form = Ext.getCmp('register');
                          values = form.getValues();



        var myStore= new Ext.data.Store({
            model: 'bluebutton.model.BlueButton.MemberList'
        });

            var newModel = Ext.ModelMgr.create({ 'memberId': 1,
                        'name': 2,
                        'imgUrl': 3
                    }, 'bluebutton.model.BlueButton.MemberList');

            myStore.add(newModel);

            myStore.sync();


                    }
                }


        ],


   }

});
```

`Model.js`

```
Ext.define('bluebutton.model.BlueButton.MemberList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        idProperty: 'memberModel',
        fields: [
            { name: 'memberId' },
            { name: 'name' },
            { name: 'imgUrl' },
            { name: 'age' },
            { name: 'address' },
            { name: 'pointAvalaible' },
            { name: 'lastVisited' },
        ],


  proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            actionMethods: {
                create : 'POST',
                read   : 'POST', // by default GET
                update : 'POST',
                destroy: 'POST'
            },
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/RESTFulExample/rest/json/metallica/testingj'
        },


    }

});
```

`Store.js`

```
Ext.define('bluebutton.store.BlueButton.MemberList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
   requires: [
              'bluebutton.model.BlueButton.MemberList'
    ],

    config: {
        grouper: {
            groupFn: function (record) {
                return record.get('name')[0];
            }
        },


           model :'bluebutton.model.BlueButton.MemberList',
           storeId :'memberStore',
           autoLoad:false,
           pageSize: 5,
           clearOnPageLoad: false, 

        data: [


        ]
    }
});
```

`Jersey.java`

```
     @POST
     @Path("/testingj")
//   @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
     @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
     public Response too(MultivaluedMap<String, String> form) {
     return Response.status(201).entity(form).build();
 }
```

But I keep getting this error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:8080/RESTFulExample/rest/json/metallica/testingj?_dc=1358408853016. 
Origin localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Please guide me solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this response because of browser's security constraint for cross origin requests, which means from javascript you can call only those urls which are in same domain. Since your service is running on 8080 post so browser consider it from other domain.

There are various ways to do cross domain request, out of which you should read about:

1. JsonP
2. Enabling CORS on server

But since mobile's security constraints are different from desktop's browser constraints so the same thing might work in mobile even though it doesn't work in browser. For more details check this out : [Loading store data with rest proxy from server in Sencha Touch 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343414/loading-store-data-with-rest-proxy-from-server-in-sencha-touch-2?answertab=votes#tab-top)

In your case I would recommend you to add JsonP support to your services and use JsonP proxy instead of AJAX & REST proxy.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Did jsonp allow to create and update record?

Comment: JsonP allows you to make GET request and as per convention write operations shouldn't be done in GET request, but if it's not avoidable  you can create or update if you want. I recommend you to read about how JsonP works