# Sencha Touch and Cookies

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, jsonp

I have a Sencha Touch 2 application.

At the moment I use JsonP to send Authentication information to a Server API (POST), the Server respond with a Json object (passed as JsonP).
The server also send a Cookie

When reloading the app the Cookie is not keept.

I need to maintain the cookie in the Sencha Touch App... Any idea how to do it?

Thanks Simone

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
    url: AshtonConfigurations.logOn,
    callbackKey: 'callback',
    method: 'POST',
    //-----------------
    withCredentials: true,
    useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
    //-----------------
    params: {
        UserName: username,
        Password: password,
        RememberMe: 'true',
        DeviceTokenNotification: pushIdToken
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since JsonP use JS embedded tag to fetch data from remote URL, so it does not support POST. And for the same reason HTTP headers & Cookies will not work.

Read this for more information : http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.JsonP

If you want to exchange cookies you have to use Ajax proxy talking to server which has CORS enabled.

FYI, desktop browser's security policy is deferent from bundled app's webview so once you build the app AJAX can work with remote servers. If you want to go that way you have to go through this thread which discuss about how to go about doing development

[How to use json proxy to access remote services during development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118053/how-to-use-json-proxy-to-access-remote-services-during-development)

There are people who suggest updates using GET request which I don't recommend.