# Which proxy to use in sencha touch 2 when i have restful api

Tags: api, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to make a sencha touch 2 mobile app. I have a restful api in server and i want to consume that in my mobile app. Which sencha proxy should i use (rest, ajax, jsonp)? Rest and ajax has issue with cross-site domain issue, so jsonp can be the solution. But how can i send jsonp request to rest api if i have parameters?

Comment: answer to question is on http://try.sencha.com/touch/2.0.1/docs/Ext.data.JsonP.1/ link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `REST` proxy if your services truly follows REST standards because that way proxy can provide you out-of-the-box functionality to operate on models.

Regarding cross-domain issues, please note that the way app behaves in desktop browser is different from its behaviour when it runs in phone so you are not forced to use `JSONP` if you don't want, `AJAX` can also work for you. Its good if you can use JSONP but please keep in mind its limitations of having no support for HTTP headers and other useful methods like POST, PUT & DELETE.

Please go through this for more information : [How to use json proxy to access remote services during development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118053/how-to-use-json-proxy-to-access-remote-services-during-development)

Comment: I have created API with REST standards. So, I am going to use REST Proxy. But is there anyway to test such app from PC browser? And what if i need to pass more than one parameters like https://url/user/$username/$password? Thanks for advice

Comment: I believe you can pass anything in URL but its better to put it in request body instead of URL. Also use HTTPS if you are dealing with password.

Comment: Can you please provide me an example of custom rest url generation?